# why vue v-for list update even though data related not changed

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Code:

```
<ul id='app'>
  <li v-for="item of items">{{ item | log }}</li>
  <model :num='num'></model> <!-- changing num will trigger <li> updates -->
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Vue.filter('log', function(v) {
  console.log(v + ' is updated!');
  return '#' + v;
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    num: 0,
    items: ['a', 'b']
  }
});
</script>
```

Without the `<model>` tag, it just works fine. But, after I add the `<model>` tag and change the value of `num`, the `v-for` is updated (`log` filter is called) at the same time .

Chrome console:

```
> app.num += 1
  a is updated!
  b is updated!
```

Anyway, the `items` has nothing to do with the `num`, It is not necessary to update. Why and what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common text formatting.

In your example you defined a global filter called `log`, according with docs:

> The filter’s function always receives the expression’s value (the result of the former chain) as its first argument.

It seems that anytime any local data change the filter `log` **gets called**, and since it's value has not changed always print the same array data, however that's not mean that the DOM gets updated.

Let's make a little experiment to prove the `li elements` are not being updated with your code example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    num: 0,
    items: ['a', 'b']
  },
  filters: {
    log: function (v) {
      return '#' + v;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleButtonClick() {
      this.num ++;
    }
  }
});

// ignore this is only to hide devtools info
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<ul id='app'>
  <li v-for="item of items">{{ items | log }}</li>
  <p>Value of num is {{ num }}</p>
  <button @click="handleButtonClick">
    Update num ++
  </button>
</ul>
```

Now open chrome dev tools and on **Elements** tabs inspect the li elements:

You should see that only num is being updated. Take a look to this screenshot as reference:

[image]